# Port 995 is blocked on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, port

I am running a Linux server and can not figure out what is blocking port 995. Firewall ist not running. Who can help?

Thanks, Hans

Comment: The information in your comment below means that you have no software running that is listening to port 995. What are you trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Is a program listening on this port ? 
You can check this:

```
ss -lnatup | grep 995
```

How you check this port ? (From server, other computer ?).
You can check this on server with command:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 995
```

or (when your application listening only on global IP)

```
telnet <SERVER_GLOBAL_IP> 995
```

When you check this from other computer, you can check the packet it comes, with tcpdump (running on server):

```
tcpdump -ni any port 995 -vvv
```

and connecting again with you other computer.

You can check firewall (iptables) with command:

```
iptables -nvL
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's really weired: No program is listening on this port and telnet gives in both cases an error: telnet localhost 995 -> Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused.
From another server I can not check: You don't have permission to capture on that device and the Firewall is not active: Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 655M packets, 221G bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination